# How to clear a ViewModel and discard SavedState manually

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

With Navigation 2.4.0 multiple back stacks were introduced. If you use the [NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) to setup a BottomNavigationView with a NavController, the state of the ViewModels associated with the destinations of the bottom navigation is saved and restored automatically (as described [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134)).

I have observed, that those ViewModels are never cleared. In my case the ViewModel is provided `by navGraphViewModels()`. If the navGraph is removed from the back stack, I would expect that the ViewModel is cleared. But it is not.

I think it should be possible to clear those kind of ViewModels and discard the saved state. For example if the user logs out and all the data becomes invalid. How can this be achieved?